# Matching Col A and B and putting answer in C

Tags: excel, vba, compare, match, lookup

For a  project I'm looking to compare Col.A and Col.A. I've added the numbers using code but cant work out how to compare the two in Col. C for example if Col.A and Col B match I want Col.C to say "yes" or "No". also if I wanted to do this with Codes and not numbers would I add just string and not int? Or what if I wanted to match dates. Any help be great as I'm just getting back into VB

The code I've worked on is below

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Cells.ClearContents
    Range("A1") = "Column A"
    Range("B1") = "Column B"
    Range("C1") = "Column C"

    Dim i As Boolean

     For i = 2 To 25
        Range("A" & i) = Int((10 - 2 + 1) * Rnd + 2)
        If i < 26 Then
            Range("B" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = _
                 Int((10 - 2 + 1) * Rnd + 2)
        End If
       Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you use Excel's built in exact function?

```
FormulaR1C1 = "=EXACT(RC[-2],RC[-1])"
```

The function will return a value of TRUE or FALSE

Before the snippet `FormulaR1C1` you'll want to input the destination cell for the formula

The `RC[-2],[RC-1]` says perform the "EXACT" calculation on the cells: 1 cell to the left and 2 cells to the left

Comment: Can you show me the code if you can I'm not lazy I'm just really bad so far I can read code and amend once I see it but can't write Please :)

Comment: `Cells(3,i).FormulaR1C1="=EXACT(RC[-2],RC[-1])"`

Comment: Assuming I wrote that correctly, this would place the exact function in Column 3 ("C"), Row i (your loop counter), and that function would compare Column -2 ("A") and Column -1 ("B") and return a value of TRUE or FALSE.